# newtons law of cooling

Tags: calculus

I need help with this calculus problem i just cant get

After 10 minutes in Jean-Luc's room, his tea has cooled to 43∘ Celsius from 100∘ Celsius. The room temperature is 23∘ Celsius. How much longer will it take to cool to 35∘? (Round to the nearest hundredth).

I solved the problem and got 13.789 multiple times but this isn't correct can anyone try solving it and show their solution for a different answer?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to subtract the initial 10 minutes? It would help if you showed your work.

Comment: The answer is 3.8mins.

Comment: that was it. nice catch, so frustrating when you miss something so simple like that

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The equation is

$43°=23°+ (100°-23°)\cdot e^{-10\cdot k}$

Do you have the same equation ?

Comment: But that wasn't his problem! He got that far.

Comment: I didn´t know that. I don´t see that he has written it in his question.

Comment: No, that is the fun of MSE. Most of the questions are written in an unhelpful way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Newton's formula ie $T_2=T_0+(T_1-T_0)e^{-kt}$ where $T_{0,1,2}$ are temperatures of surroundings initial temp and $t$(time). and final temp respectively we can approximately use $\frac{T_1-T_2}{t}=-k(\frac{T_1+T_2}{2}-T_0)$. using first condition ie cooling from (100 to 43...) get $-k$ and then substituting all values in the new equation to cool down to $35$ degrees we get the time (t).

Comment: so what answer did you get?

Comment: 4.255 minutes ...

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {dT}{dt} = -k(T-23)\\
(T-23) = A e^{-kt}\\
T(0) = 100\\
A = 77\\
T(10) = 43\\
20 = 77 e^{-10k}\\
10 k = \ln {77} - \ln{20}\\
k  \text{ ~ } 0.135\\
(35-23) = A e^{-kt}\\
\ln 12 = \ln 77-kt\\
t = \frac {10(\ln 77- \ln 12)}{\ln 77 - \ln 20}$

I get 13.789, too.

Comment: Thus making the same mistake as the OP, because the question asked for how much *longer*!

Comment: Failing to closely read the question is  my most frequent mistake.

Comment: The problem is the time pressure. It is extremely frustrating to spend 5-10 mins writing an answer, only to have someone else put it up 20 seconds before you do.